# Shape Mismatch in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nltk, tensor

I am relatively new to TensorFlow and trying to implement my first model in production.  The model trained and tested well, but using this algorithm to move to production, I've found quite challenging.  Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the following error at my evaluation line?

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1095277) for Tensor 'input:0', which has shape '(?, 2912)'
```

The code which I'm implementing is (I've tried all sorts of different methods to get this to work):

Which tensor has a length of 1x1095277?

```
def use_neural_network(input_data, lexicon,stopWords):
    x= tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, 2912], name='input')
    y= tf.placeholder('float', name='output')

    #x = tf.Variable('float', [None, 2912]', name='input')
    #y = tf.Variable('float', name='output')

    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2912, 1])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}
    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 2])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2])),}
    def neural_network_model(data):
        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
        output = tf.matmul(l1,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']
        return output

    prediction = neural_network_model(x) 
    saver=tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess,"model.ckpt")   
        lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        current_words = word_tokenize(input_data.lower())
        current_words = [re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", i) for i in current_words]
        current_words = [re.sub("\s{1,10}"," ", i) for i in current_words]
        current_words = [i for i in current_words if i not in stopWords]   
        current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
        features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))
        for word in current_words:
            if word.lower() in lexicon:
                index_value = lexicon.index(word.lower())
                features[index_value] += 1
                print(pd.Series(features).sum())
            features = np.array(list(features))
            result = (sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[features]}),1)))
            if result[0] == 0:
                print('No:',input_data)
            elif result[0] == 1:
                print('Yes:',input_data)

with open('lexicon_1.pickle','rb') as f:
    lexicon = pickle.load(f)
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
use_neural_network('I do not understand the problem', lexicon, stopWords)
```

Comment: Not sure how is this related to `nltk` but I understand =)

Comment: Put all your preprocessing with `nltk` before the tensorflow code. Write out the pre-processed data to (pickle/json/xml) file and read it, vectorize it before the tensorflow code. That'll help a lot when it comes to speed.

Comment: Good tip. I wasn't sure if my lexicon was not run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your network expects an input of size `[2912, 1]`, as defined by `hidden_1_layer`

```
hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2912, 1])), ...
```

When you call predictions, you do not call it with an input of size `[2912, 1]`, but rather with inputs equal to the length of your lexicon, which (probably) contains 1095277 numbers.

```
features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))
```

Also I suspect you are wrapping the `features` array twice, first with `features = np.array(list(features))` and then again with `x:[features]`. Not completely confident on your data, but this feels wrong.

Personally, I find it easiest to learn by copying from a tutorial and modifying lines, rather than attempting to write from scratch.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction!  It was the length of lexicon had not been truncated and was 1M large!  Thanks so much for giving me the idea.

Comment: Turns out the computer does exactly what you program it to do.